# UPDATE MySQL table with HAVING clause

Tags: mysql, unique-key

I created slug field for a table and they need to be unique but some of them aren't so i think i can add random characters at the end of them to make them unique.

So this is my SELECT query:

```
SELECT slug,count(*) as num FROM table GROUP BY slug HAVING num > 1
```

This is the UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE table SET slug = CONCAT(slug,'-',SUBSTRING(MD5(NOW()),1,2))
```

I couldn't manage to combine this 2 queries.

Comment: To use `HAVING` you must also use `GROUP BY slug`. Otherwise, MySQL will probably give you incorrect results (most other RDBMS would report a parse error)

Comment: Is your goal to modify the rows returned by the first query?

Comment: upss i forgot to write group by, i edited the query, thanks.
Yes my goal is modifying rows returned by the first query.

Comment: But given non-unique values, do you want to preserve the original for one of them, or add to all of them? Please post a sample table of what the input and output should look like.

Comment: Yes one of them may be preserved but others should be modified randomly so that they will be unique. You can see some slugs and their counts here: http://prntscr.com/7mcnnv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE mytable AS m
JOIN (SELECT slug
      FROM mytable 
      GROUP BY slug 
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t
ON m.slug = t.slug      
SET m.slug = CONCAT(m.slug,'-',SUBSTRING(MD5(NOW()),1,2))
```

However the problem with the above is that it *does not* generate unique string values.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea50d4/1)

One way to get around this, is to use row numbers calculated by variables:

```
UPDATE mytable AS m
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_number:=0, @slug := '') AS vars 
JOIN (
   SELECT slug
   FROM mytable 
   GROUP BY slug 
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) AS t ON m.slug = t.slug       
SET m.slug = CONCAT(m.slug, 
                    '-',
                    IF (@slug = m.slug,
                         IF (@slug := m.slug,@row_number:=@row_number+1, 
                                             @row_number:=@row_number+1),
                         IF (@slug := m.slug, @row_number:=1, 
                                              @row_number:=1)) 
                   )
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20520/2)

Comment: Your second suggestion solved my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
UPDATE t ,
(  SELECT slug FROM t 
  GROUP BY slug HAVING count(*) > 1
) x
SET  t.slug = CONCAT(t.slug,'-',SUBSTRING(MD5(rand()),1,2))
WHERE t.slug = x.slug
;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01c68/1

I am using `rand()` instead of `now()` because the latter won't give unique strings.